# NodeRED: Configuration lost after modifying flows.json

Tags: mqtt, node-red

I have a working flow using MQTT publisher and subscribe nodes and one broker configuration. Everything works.

Before starting up NodeRED, I have to change the MQTT broker ip and port with environment variables `MQTT_BROKER_IP` and `MQTT_BROKER_PORT`.

To do that I use

```
sed -i -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*\"broker\":[[:blank:]]*\)\"[^\"]*\",/\1\"$MQTT_BROKER_IP\",/g" /data/flows.json
sed -i -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*\"port\":[[:blank:]]*\)\"[^\"]*\",/\1\"$MQTT_BROKER_PORT\",/g" /data/flows.json
```

The substitutions works.

Now, the problem is, that when NodeRED starts up there is an error in the logfile:

```
[info] Starting flows
[error] [mqtt out:2b1fba1a.efa24e] missing broker configuration
[error] [mqtt in:58c7bd6b.0e8664] missing broker configuration
```

When I go to the NodeRED Editor, open the MQTT nodes, save them without modifying anything and deploy the flow, everything works and the MQTT nodes get a green "connected" light.

Why does this happen? How do I have to modify flows.json outside NodeRED correctly?

Comment: Have you tried comparing flows.json from before and after the "open the MQTT nodes, save them without modifying anything" step? (likely there will be a minor change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the json field `broker` is used by multiple entries in the flow for different things. e.g.

The `mqtt-broker` config node that you are trying to edit:

```
{
    "id": "c2ba2a60.80ae38",
    "type": "mqtt-broker",
    "z": "",
    "name": "",
    "broker": "192.168.1.116",
    "port": "1883",
    "clientid": "",
    "usetls": false,
    "compatmode": false,
    "keepalive": "60",
    "cleansession": true,
    "birthTopic": "",
    "birthQos": "0",
    "birthPayload": "",
    "closeTopic": "",
    "closeQos": "0",
    "closePayload": "",
    "willTopic": "",
    "willQos": "0",
    "willPayload": ""
  }
```

And the `mqtt-in` node:

```
{
  "id": "98d0e95b.c28c2",
  "type": "mqtt in",
  "z": "a4de5120.cd3f58",
  "name": "",
  "topic": "#",
  "qos": "0",
  "datatype": "auto",
  "broker": "c2ba2a60.80ae38",
  "x": 190,
  "y": 80,
  "wires": [
    []
  ]
}
```

As you can see the when you run your sed script it will also change `broker` the entry in the `mqtt-in` node that points to the `mqtt-broker`.

The open/save probably works because you only have one `mqtt-broker` defined so it will default to be selected in the list so fixes that entry when you deploy.

If you want to do this sort of thing you will need something more complex that is aware of the `type` entry in each JSON entry it is updating.

Comment: Great. That was the problem, Thank you very much! I changed the sed search pattern to ignore anything that contains exatly one dot (broker node id).

Comment: To write the the sed pattern its important to know that the node id's are two hex numbers being combined with a dot.